# Hanging a large bowl on a stone backsplash

Tags: tile, hanging, stone

I'm desperately seeking an answer to how I can hang a beautiful decorative shallow bowl between my stovetop and my range hood.  The bowl is about about 15 inches across and 3 or so inches deep.  It is absolutely perfect for the spot, but I can't figure out how to anchor it properly.

Comment: What are the bowl and backsplash made of? Are you aiming to mount it permanently or in a fashion where it is removable? Do you want it inset in the wall or mounted over the surface? Do you have an example of similar look that you'd like to imitate? Pictures would be very helpful too.

Comment: What do you want it to look like?  Also probably will need a pic to see what you are talking about.

Comment: depending on the type of stone diamond drill bits could be used to make mounting holes. the finer the stone the slower you will need to cut to keep it from cracking.

Answer (score 1):

I would find a hanger you like along the lines of this one that's deep enough for your bowl:

[image]

Then I'd hang it from a screw placed inside or behind your range hood. I'm assuming that it's a sheet metal hood with a hollow underside.

If the bowl is too high, use a decorative chain or rope to connect the top of the hanger with the screw at the desired height.